# Using window.opener.document.FormName.VarName.value to pass data to dynamic parent window

Tags: javascript

I am passing data like stated in the title all over, but now I want to pass it to dynamic page. I have a repetition of same input field for random number of iterations.
I am passing the name of this input field to my child window, so I could use it there to pass the data back, but don't know how.

This is part of the code, where I return values, where A is the name of input field where value B should return

```
function MyFunction(A, B) {
window.opener.document.myFormName.A.value = b;
window.close();
}
```

But window.opener line obviously doesn't work that way. Any help would be appreciated!
Marcel

Comment: Can you put the same example in Jsfiddle.

Comment: I have already solved it. But the solution will be even harder to explain as the problem.
I have inserted value, in variable A directly into code already on the server side. So on the client side function is put together correctly.